# Why isn't rspec memoizing this?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test which is a bit like the following.  The details isn't important, but I have a method which takes about 10 seconds, and gets back some data which I want to use a bunch of times in a bunch of tests.  The data won't be any more fresh - I only need to fetch it once.  My understanding of let is that it memoizes, so I would expect the following to only call slow_thing once.  But I see it called as many times as I refer to slowthing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
describe 'example' do

  def slow_thing
    puts "CALLING ME!"
    sleep(100)
  end

  let(:slowthing) { slow_thing }

  it 'does something slow' do
    expect(slowthing).to be_true
  end

  it 'does another slow thing' do
    expect(slowthing).to be_true
  end

end
```

When I run the test, I see CALLING ME! as many times as I have assertions or use slowthing.

Comment: use `before(:all)` instead

Answer (score 5):

The documentation states values are *not* cached across examples:

> The value will be cached across multiple calls in the same example **but not across examples**. [Emphasis mine.]

E.g., also from the docs:

```
$count = 0
describe "let" do
  let(:count) { $count += 1 }

  it "memoizes the value" do
    count.should == 1
    count.should == 1
  end

  it "is not cached across examples" do
    count.should == 2
  end
end
```

From https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: Thanks - I was relying on memory... mea culpa.

Comment: @bbcmicro This was a different example, so it wasn't memoized.